# NestJS Shared Modules

Tags: nestjs

I am reading `Modules` in NestJS official documentation and I wanted to try shared modules.

So, I have the following structure for my application:

```
src
├── cats
│   ├── cats.controller.ts
|   ├── cats.module.ts
|   └── cats.service.ts
├── users
│   ├── users.controller.ts
|   ├── users.module.ts
|   └── users.service.ts
├── app.controller.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── app.service.ts
└── main.ts
```

I understand that modules are singletons and shared modules by default in NestJS so long as you export its service and import its module to another module. [Read it here.](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#:%7E:text=In%20Nest%2C%20modules%20are%20singletons%20by%20default%2C%20and%20thus%20you%20can%20share%20the%20same%20instance%20of%20any%20provider%20between%20multiple%20modules%20effortlessly.)

On my end, I want to see whether it is true and so I did not follow the documentation and instead imported directly the `cats.service.ts` into another service called `users.service.ts`, like the below:

`src/users/users.controller.ts`

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './user.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
 constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get('get-cats')
  getCats() {
    return this.usersService.getCats();
  }
}
```

`src/users/users.service.ts`, I imported it here directly.

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CatsService } from 'src/cats/cats.service.ts';


@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  getCats() {
    return new CatsService().findAll();
  }
}
```

However, it seems that it works fine because I can actually see all the cats when I go to the path `localhost:3000/users/get-cats`.

I am expecting to get something like `must import x inside y to access this service` or like any error that prevents me from doing so. Is there something that I missed or did not understand?

**Edit:**

What I did not follow is this [particular line](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20do%20that%2C%20we%20first%20need%20to%20export%20the%20CatsService%20provider%20by%20adding%20it%20to%20the%20module%27s%20exports%20array%2C%20as%20shown%20below%3A) in the official documentation:

`In order to do that, we first need to export the CatsService provider by adding it to the module's exports array. Now any module that imports the CatsModule has access to the CatsService and will share the same instance with all other modules that import it as well.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, that is totally possible. But the question is whether it is a good idea to do this?

You basically just created a new instance of the `CatsService` class. Of course you can do that. There is (obviously) nothing to stop you from doing this plain Typescript logic. Nevertheless CatsService will not be a singleton which can be injected in other services. You have created your own instance and do not benefit from dependency injection (provided by NestJS) anymore.

What happens if you want to pass dependencies to your `CatsService` constructor? You would have to pass them also in the place where you are creating the `CatsService` yourself (`new CatsService(...dependencies)`).

Basically NestJS can be seen as a framework in order to handle dependencies based on the annotations passed to classes. You are free to just ignore the annotations and handle dependency injection yourself. Nevertheless this would result in getting rid of the handy features NestJS provides. This way you would also need to handle the logic of creating singletons as well (if you want to ensure that these classes are instantiated as singletons).

Example:

Calling `new CatsService()` multiple times in your application would lead to many instances of this class being created. Passing the service to your constructor like `constructor(catsService: CatsService)` would lead to one instance being created and then this **single** instance will be injected into different other objects.

Comment: I am kind of confused. Why is calling `new CatsService()` multiple times create many instances? I thought they are singleton in nature. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Yes, you are :D `CatsService` itself is not a singleton, it's just a plain typescript class. When you call `new CatsService()`, you are creating a new object of this class (each time you call it). What Nestjs does is create only a single object (singleton) and pass it to each constructor where this type is used. Quote from NestJS providers page: Nest will resolve the catsService by creating and returning an instance of CatsService (or, in the normal case of a singleton, returning the existing instance if it has already been requested elsewhere).